# How can I extract a subset of GPS points for a specific area from a larger GPS dataset?

Tags: gps, subset

I have a large dataset of GPS points. There is one geographic area I want to focus on so I want to be able to extract the GPS points that fall within that area. How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You define the geographic area via a polygon in latitude,longitude coordinates.

Then you use a `isPointInPolygon(longitude, latitude)` method.

If that returns `true` the GPS point is inside.

So simple.